# Getting 403: forbiden responce when i navigate to link using loop

Tags: cypress, web-api-testing

I am checking the `API` response using loop but getting `403: Forbidden` for the last two scripts.
Here is my script.

[image]

Please check below image `XPath //a[5]` and `XPath //a[6]` working fine but getting an error in `XPath //a[7]`

Also, get the status code `200` when I check in `Postman`. Here are screenshots for postman please check them.

[image]

What is the problem here anyone can help me.

This is my test code. getting error for only `XPath //a[5]` and `XPath //a[6]`.

```
it('Navigate through the links using loops', () => {
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token')
cy.visit('hubs/26/brain');
cy.get('.notification-dismiss').click();
 cy
 .xpath("//a[1]")
 .then(link => {
      cy
     .request(link.prop('href'))
     .its('status')
     .should('eq', 200);

 });
 cy
 .xpath("//a[2]")
 .then(link => {
      cy
     .request(link.prop('href'))
     .its('status')
     .should('eq', 200);

 });
cy
  .xpath("//a[3]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
cy
  .xpath("//a[4]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
cy
  .xpath("//a[5]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
cy
  .xpath("//a[6]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
cy
  .xpath("//a[7]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
cy
  .xpath("//a[8]")
  .then(link => {
    cy
      .request(link.prop('href'))
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200);
  });
```

});

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the code or a scrubbed version of it.

Comment: Please check my code

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if you can be waiting for a request that has already been completed.

cy.wait() accepts also an array of aliases so you can first collect all aliases and then wait for all of them with a single cy.wait().

```
const aliases = [];
for (let i = 0; i < requestUrls.length; i++) {
  aliases.push(`@request${i}`);
  ...
}

cy.wait(aliases);
```

But it is better if you can share the code and details.